# Understanding authentication and session management using Spring boot

Tags: java, session, spring-boot, spring-mongo

I have made a spring boot project with mongo db as backend. I want to ensure that users are authenticated and authorized while maintaining some kind of in memory session (using redis or something in built in spring session)
I have been through lot of turorials like [this](https://github.com/sedooe/blog-projects), [this](https://github.com/Zuehlke/springboot-sec-tutor), [this](http://www.sedooe.com/2016/04/rest-authentication-using-spring-security-and-spring-session/) etc

All of them ask you to extend `WebSecurityConfigAdapter`, configure `HttpSecurity` and provide a `UserDetailService`. Which I have done the following way.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return new StockUserDetailService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/broker/**").hasAnyAuthority("BROKER")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
}
```

But what I don't understand is where is the sessin management taking place and what is the `url` that the user should use to login? If I write a controller with mapping for `/login`, what should my action be inside the login controller. I really am not getting the whole picture.

**UPDATE**

I tried posting to `/login`. I get this error

```
{
"timestamp": 1494842451672,
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.",
"path": "/login"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring manages the `/login` route for you. You just have to send the POST request to it with the user credentials. If you want to specify another login URL you can do with `.loginProcessingUrl("/myCustomLoginUrl")`
For `UserDetailsService` you have to provide your own implementation which implements the `loadUserByUsername(String userName)` method which retrieves the user from databse or any persistence storage you are using and returns a `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` with corresponding authorities. Please see the following official docs: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: I tried posting to "/login". But it gives forbidden error. check my update

Comment: It is a CSRF token issue.Either provide a csrf token in a hidden field in your form, or disable in your security config with `.csrf(). disable()`